# Node.js application not detected by Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku

I created a small site in Visual Studio and used Node.js and Express. I can access it via Visual Studio and with Heroku local web. However, when trying to push it to Heroku, I get the error:  Application not supported by 'heroku/nodejs' buildpack

I read through the documentation provided by Heroku, but didn't find any solution.

```
ERROR: Application not supported by 'heroku/nodejs' buildpack
remote:  !
remote:  !     The 'heroku/nodejs' buildpack is set on this application, but was
remote:  !     unable to detect a Node.js codebase.
remote:  !
remote:  !     A Node.js app on Heroku requires a 'package.json' at the root of
remote:  !     the directory structure.
remote:  !
remote:  !     If you are trying to deploy a Node.js application, ensure that this
remote:  !     file is present at the top level directory. This directory has the
remote:  !     following files:
remote:  !
remote:  !     Portfolio/
remote:  !     Portfolio.sln
remote:  !
remote:  !     If you are trying to deploy an application written in another
remote:  !     language, you need to change the list of buildpacks set on your
remote:  !     Heroku app using the 'heroku buildpacks' command.
remote:  !
remote:  !     For more information, refer to the following documentation:
remote:  !     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks
remote:  !     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#activation
```

Comment: Does your application have a package.json file? Without one, Heroku won't know how to run your application or which dependencies to install. How have you been installing your dependencies locally?

Comment: Yes it does, it was automatically created

Comment: Where is it located in your directory structure? If it's not in the root directory of the project it won't be usable. Based on that error output it looks like the top level directory does not contain package.json.

Comment: i just checked via git show master:package.json. The console gave the following error:
fatal: Path 'Portfolio/package.json' exists, but not 'package.json'. Did you mean 'master:Portfolio/package.json' aka 'master:./package.json'?

Comment: Cool, looks like your package.json is nested under Portfolio instead of in the top level directory for your project. Move the file to the top level directory and try deploying again.

Comment: When moving it up to the top-level directory and searching for package.json again, the following error is given:

fatal: Path 'package.json' exists on disk, but not in 'master'

Comment: That's a git problem; you've moved the file locally, i.e. on disk, but have not committed it and merged your changes into the master branch. You're searching your git tree for the file, not your file system. If you're just deploying to Heroku from the command line this shouldn't matter but if you're trying to deploy from some kind of CI pipeline that reads from your master branch on Github, you should commit and push the changes. Did you try to deploy again after moving it?

Comment: `cd` into the project root directory and run `ls` - do you see your package.json?

Comment: i just had to redo everything in the command line and it solved it, thank you

Comment: try renaming the file to server.js it detects automatically and add a package.json using npm init

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error output is pretty straightforward - make sure your package.json is in the top level directory for your project and try deploying again. Based on your comment, it seems that package.json is located at `{project_root}/Portfolio/package.json` instead of `{project_root}/package.json`.

Answer (score 2):

Look at this error message.

#### A Node.js app on Heroku requires a 'package.json' at the root of the directory structure.

Do your package.json is on root directory ?

Comment: i just checked via git show master:package.json. The console gave the following error: fatal: Path 'Portfolio/package.json' exists, but not 'package.json'. Did you mean 'master:Portfolio/package.json' aka 'master:./package.json'?.

So i guess its not in root directory, whats the best way to move it?

Comment: You can create it by typing **npm init** and than **npm install**

Comment: Or simply drag and drop to the root directory . If any error please do let me know